# Is there interest in maintaining chef cookbooks for ROS?

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Chef is my tool of choice for configuration management. It's pretty easy-to-use, has strong community and solid integration with VMs and clouds. I'd like to use it to provision all my ROS-based development VMs and physical nodes.

I found a couple uses of it with ROS:

- https://github.com/ull-isaatc/grull_vagrant/blob/master/cookbooks/ros/
- https://github.com/garaemon/garaemon-settings/tree/master/chef/site-cookbooks/ros

(sorry, not enough karma to publish links properly)

Both seem to be parts of personal/project setups that could be refactored/extracted into standalone cookbooks.

What would chef be good for? Building fully-configured systems that are ready to run:

- building VMs with ROS: ready to run, do development, run tests
- makes CI configuration easy
- pulling 3rd party dependencies (bag files, models, etc) that project-specific and aren't part of an install
- building boxes in the cloud with ROS

Q1: Is there interest?

Q2: Am I missing other existing examples?

Q3: What do people use right now?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174507/is-there-interest-in-maintaining-chef-cookbooks-for-ros?/) by [syrnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/18511/syrnick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm the author of https://github.com/garaemon/garaemon-settings/tree/master/chef/site-cookbooks/ros, however
I have no passion about maitaining this cookbook yet.

Now I'm using simple shell script https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_common/blob/master/jsk.rosbuild rather than chef cookbook to build ROS environment.

---

Originally posted by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) with karma: 317 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syrnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/18511/syrnick/) on 2014-06-26**:
Can you elaborate on your motivation for not using chef? Not necessary? Hard to maintain? Something else?

**Comment by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) on 2014-07-06**:
It was hard to maintain and I think the effort to maintain it is not worth to the effect.